# Systemd hangs before TTY during boot in archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, boot, tty, gdm3

systemd of my archlinux hangs since this morning without any error message and before TTY. So, I cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. The last thing I see is Reached Target Bluetooth. But everything looks fine except it does not boot into GDM.

Although I know that systemd itself causes this issue, as it is very well explained [here](http://osquestions.com/unix-Linux/120634/why-does-my-arch-install-hang-at-random-stages-during-boot).

What can I do to reach either TTY or login?

**Edit:** After hours of trying, I have not found any solution. I tried to autologin with gdm, to disable it, checked fstab to no avail, checked journalctl (which does not show an issues), fscked sda3, tried to get online to update the system (which has failed), I can access files like fstab via a Live-CD like Knoppix but nothing has helped. It's a pity.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. If you know what you are capable of doing, asking how to do that, makes your post a much better question. Asking about whether people are capable of assisting you (for which the only appropriate answers are "Yes, someone can help you out" or "No, nobody can help you out").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine did the same. Did you happen to try to install updates using Gnome's update-at-shutdown feature?

Anyway, here's what fixed it for me:

1. Boot to GRUB (or whatever bootloader you use), and edit the kernel command line so that it has `systemd.unit=graphical.target`. Then let it boot using the new parameters.
2. GDM should start, and you should be able to log in as normal.
3. When you reboot, it should be unwedged.

I don't *know*, but my hypothesis is that the update feature changes the default boot target, temporarily, and the update target is somehow borked.

Comment: Hi, ams, thank you very much for this answer. You saved me! I guess, this was the problem. Yes, I used indeed Gnome's update-at-shutdown feature. I have one little issue, though, I cannot get into `GRUB`, since `GRUB_HIDDEN-TIMEOUT=0`. Do you know by any chance if I can just change `/etc/default/grub` within a Live CD without `chroot`?

Comment: You can change `/boot/grub.cfg` directly, or you can change `/etc/default/grub` and then regenerate `grub.cfg`. I always have a 1 second GRUB timeout so I can break in if I'm quick.

Comment: It happened to me again, and the `multi-user.target` step was unnecessary, so I updated my answer.

Comment: The install-updates-on-shutdown feature appears to be working again now. I just used it without anything breaking.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update, ams! Are this install-updates-on-shutdown actually necessary to do if you do otherwise the regular updates via CLI?

Comment: Nope, it's just a convenient way to do the same thing (although I noticed gnome-software doesn't seem to bother with a few, obscure packages).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It was caused by systemd after update bragging that getty@tty1.service file was not a symlink. Making it a symlink to library fixed the issue.